# Isotope Plugin: Only generating filters for specific categories?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I used a [tutorial](https://www.aliciaramirez.com/2014/03/integrating-isotope-with-wordpress/) provided by [Alicia Ramirez](https://www.aliciaramirez.com/) to set up the [Isotope Plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) for a Wordpress page. My goal is a simple masonry layout for the posts + the option to filter them.

Through the tutorial I learned how to generate filters for all categories set up in the backend and subsequently load all posts. This is done with this piece of code:

```
<ul id="filters" class="cat-filter">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">Alles</a></li>
    <?php 
        $terms = get_terms("category");         // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy
        $count = count($terms);                 // How many are they?
        if ( $count > 0 ){                      // If there are more than 0 terms
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {       // for each term:
                echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
                //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
            }
        } 
    ?>
</ul>
```

I would like to know how I might be able to only generate filters and load posts of a specific set of categories, rather than all of them. Can I do so by changing the initial piece of code which gets all categories via `$terms = get_terms("category");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_terms` also accepts an array of arguments that contains parameters to specify which terms you want returned.

You don't say how you will identify your specific categories, so I'll use the term names in the example, but you can change it to search by [slug, term id, meta_query or anything else that is allowed](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/).

Example get terms for terms named "news" and "events" only

```
$args = array( 'names' => array( "news", "events")); 
$terms = get_terms("category", $args);
```

If you wanted to get terms for specific ids, you would use something like: 
    $args = array( 'include' => array( 1,4,7 )); // term ids 1,4 and 7 only

Ref: [All parameters allowed in $args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/)